# Debian installer doesn't detect disk

Tags: debian, system-installation, debian-installer

I had Debian installed next to Win10 on my Dell XPS 15 9560, but a few days ago some Windows update damaged it and this was showing to me (and it was displaying `initramfs` prompt):
[image: errors]
So I formatted the Debian partition and tried to install it again. Unfortunately the same errors are displaying before the installer launches. Then, in partitioning manager, the only disk that shows is the USB stick, where the installer resides:
[image: partitioning manager]
I have looked up very many sites, but I have found no solution that works for me.
I also attach the output of `fdisk -l` command as it may be useful:
[image: fdisk -l output]

Comment: So on that 32 GB partition you have both Windows 10 and Linux Debian? Can you separate them, each on it's Hard Disk Drive?

Comment: @Fido-X No, 32 GB is the installation USB stick. I want to install Debian on 512 GB SSD, which doesn't show up here and this is the problem.

Comment: Try to run **lshw**, if it doesn't work try **df -H** and tell us what you get.

Comment: Is that 512 GB invisible HDD detected in BIOS? If yes is it IDE or SATA? If it's SATA, could you set it to run in IDE mode?

Comment: @Fido-X `lshw` gives `/bin/sh: lshw: not found` and `df -H` gives `Usage: df [Pkmh] [FILESYSTEM]...`

Comment: And in the meantime I tried downgrading and upgrading BIOS firmware and it also didn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73319/discussion-between-fido-x-and-leftismer).

Comment: When you formatted the Debian partition, did you do it with Windows and create an NTFS filesystem on it?

Comment: @user276596 Did you find a solution to this?